# How to use commands on files inside directories starting with a special character?

Tags: command-line, command, special-characters

The [Angular 2 style conventions](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#-a-id-04-12-a-prefix-lazy-loaded-folders-with-) says that lazy loaded folders should start with a plus sign (`+`).

This works fine when doing `cd +directory/`, but becomes problematic when using commands on files inside those directories from outside. `vim +folder/file.ts` does not work. Doing `git rm --cached **/*.js*` in the base directory, will ignore all files inside directories with `+`. Quoting the command arguments did not work.

I could just ditch the concept of `+directory`, but I appreciate conventions.

How to use commands on files inside directories starting with a special character?

Comment: @TobySpeight I've noticed about half of the questions labeled 'terminal' have nothing to do with it. Perhaps worth it raising a meta question how to handle this situation.

Comment: @TobySpeight yes, I made a mistake.

Comment: @egmont you can handle the situation by editting any question that uses the wrong tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of commands (`head`/`tail`, `sort`, `sh`, `vim`...) treat arguments that start with `+` specially, so it's not a good idea to use that as the first character of a file name. Same goes for `-` which is even more commonly used as option leader character.

Like for `-`, to avoid that `+` being treated specially, you could use a `./` prefix. `./+foo` is another path to `+foo` that doesn't start with `+`. That `./` trick also helps for other situations where arguments are treated differently based on their content. For instance, it helps with `awk` for file names that contain `=` (compare `awk 1 a=b` with `awk 1 ./a=b`) or for filenames with `:` for ImageMagick commands.

For some commands that recognise `+x` as an option, using `--` to mark the end of options may also help. Generally, it works in fewer situations than the `./` prefix though.

Answer (score 1):

If a program should stop interpreting commandline arguments as (potential) options and start seeing them as e.g. files you use `--` after the "real" option(s):

```
vim -- +folder/file.ts
gif rm --cached -- **/*.js*
```

not all programs implement this, but most modern ones do.