# What purpose does dot slash serve?

Tags: command-line, files

As I understand it:

- `./filename` executes `filename` as a script.
- `./` indicates the current directory.

What purpose (if any) does the ./ serve if precedes a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) (filter):

```
qpdf --empty --pages ./*.pdf(nOn) -- output.pdf
```

The question is posed because execution without the `./` seems to produce the same result.

Comment: Probably related to this: [grep getting confused by filenames with dashes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364922/grep-getting-confused-by-filenames-with-dashes)

Comment: That is usually a protection against files starting with a dash being interpreted as options to the command. Consider `touch -a` vs `touch ./-a`.

Comment: relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/302059/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/110750/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170014/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490535/117549

Comment: See also [What is the difference between "du -sh \*" and "du -sh ./\*"?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/110750)

Answer (score 2):

Prefixing `./` (or any path) prevents filenames starting with a dash from being taken as options.

```
$ touch ./-l foo bar
$ ls
bar  foo  -l
$ ls *
-rw-r--r-- 1 ilkkachu ilkkachu 0 Nov  3 15:10 bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 ilkkachu ilkkachu 0 Nov  3 15:10 foo
```

The root issue is that it's the *shell* that expands the wildcard, and when e.g. `ls` sees the argument `-l`, it can't know if it came from a filename wildcard, or if the user wrote it by hand.

Above, the file called `-l` caused `ls` to switch to the long listing. Another such filename could have ended up with an `invalid option` error. Or worse, if the command was `rm`, and you had a file called `-rf`.

That's just one of the issues that's arguably "wrong" with the relaxed attitude Unix systems take on file names. For more than you want to know, see e.g. these essays from David Wheeler:

- [Fixing Unix/Linux/POSIX Filenames:
  Control Characters (such as Newline), Leading Dashes, and Other Problems](https://dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html)
- [Filenames and Pathnames in Shell: How to do it Correctly](https://dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html)

Answer (score 1):

The dot-slash construct doesn't "execute `filename` as a script" - it is a directive to the shell (or whatever other program is interpreting the input) to "look in the current directory". It is most often prepended to a command (binary or script) when that command is in the current working directory and when the current working directory is not in the search path. Using it within a command (as in your `qpdf` example) is a way to get source files from a different directory when you expect output files to drop into the directory you're in when you invoke the command.